# How to access guest VMs from outside network?

Tags: 12.04, networking, virtualization

My problem is how to access guest VM from outside network. 
I am going to describe my problem in details.

I have single machine with Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS contains two NICs. One NIC is connected to my gateway(i.e. 10.0.0.1) and 10.0.0.3 is IP address of this interface. Another NIC has IP 192.168.0.3 but this is a part of Bridge(i.e. br0).

I created two guest Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Desktop VMs with IP address 192.168.0.100 and 192.168.0.110.

My `/etc/network/interfaces` file is as following:

**The loopback network interface**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

**The primary network interface**

```
auto eth2
iface eth2 inet manual

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.3
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.0.0
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
    gateway 10.0.0.1
    bridge_ports eth2
    bridge_fd 9
    bridge_hello 2
    bridge_maxage 12
    bridge_stp off
```

I am able to ping to 10.0.0.3 from guest VM. But I am unable to ping gateway (i.e. 10.0.0.1). I already had a IP forwarding enable in `/etc/sysctl.conf`. But I am able to access the Internet from by host OS.

Can I get help to access 10.0.0.1 and other networks from guest VMs?

Comment: What VM manager are you using? This may be specific to your router, which we are unable to help with.

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart your network to make your changes active?

Use this:

sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart

so that your bridges become active.

Comment: I tried setting "Bridged adapter" and restarting the networking service. ifconfig command displays a ip address for the guest machine as 10.210.x.x, but I can not connect to the guest vm from my host machine through putty. What could be wrong?